# debowerify and coffeeify interaction

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bower, browserify

When I use `debowerify` with `coffeeify` got problem that `bootstrap` cannot find jquery (in browser error):

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery bootstrap.js:7
```

where my `source.coffee` file is:

```
$ = jQuery = require ('jquery')
require('bootstrap')
bootstrap_enabled = (typeof $().modal == 'function')
console.log "bootstrap_enabled"
console.log bootstrap_enabled
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap_test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "main": "browserify source.coffee  -t coffeeify -t debowerify  > main.js --debug"
  },
  "bootstrap": {
    "depends": [
      "jquery:$"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^6.0.2",
    "coffeeify": "^0.7.0",
    "debowerify": "^0.8.2"
  }
}
```

`jquery` and `bootstrap` are installed via `bower`.

But when I use the only `debowerify` without `coffeeify` the bootstrap is loaded ok:

```
$ = jQuery = require ('jquery');
require('bootstrap');

browserify source.js -t debowerify > main.js --debug
```

So the problem is in interaction of `debowerify` and `coffeeify`. How to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in adding `window`. before `jQuery =`:

```
$ = window.jQuery = require ('jquery')
require('bootstrap')
bootstrap_enabled = (typeof $().modal == 'function')
console.log "bootstrap_enabled"
console.log bootstrap_enabled
```

Now it all works ok.